# jQuery get original $(this) after transferring to another DOM node?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Is it possible to combine this into a single line? You can't do this:

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('active').addClass('active');
```

Because the selected DOM node is now all the siblings instead of the original node, since you transfersed (sp?) away from your original selection.

I'm wondering if there is some selector that selects your original selection again that you can chain onto the first line, so that it's all in one line.

Comment: Can you not do `$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');` ?

Comment: @Lobo In this case, that would work, but there are situations where it wouldn't - e.g. if one line used `.siblings()` and the other used `.find(something)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive what you are looking for is [the `.end()` function](http://api.jquery.com/end/). To quote from that documentation:

> Most of jQuery's DOM traversal methods operate on a jQuery object instance and produce a new one, matching a different set of DOM elements. When this happens, it is as if the new set of elements is pushed onto a stack that is maintained inside the object. Each successive filtering method pushes a new element set onto the stack. If we need an older element set, we can use end() to pop the sets back off of the stack.

Comment: Brilliant. How did I never know about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
```